# GCP logging to elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

We have elasticsearch running on VMs and we are trying to share the logs from GCP to local elastic cluster.

Thing is, GCP uses service account and key. Is there a way where we can add GCP service account credentials to elastic for authentication/communication.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Elasticsearch connector lets you connect to a [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/webinars/getting-started-elasticsearch) search engine and perform the supported search engine operations.
 
You can check the steps in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/integration-connectors/docs/connectors/elasticsearch/configure).
 
As a reminder, this product or feature is covered by the [Pre-GA Offerings Terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#1) of the Google Cloud Terms of Service. Pre-GA products and features might have limited support, and changes to pre-GA products and features might not be compatible with other pre-GA versions. For more information, see the [launch stage descriptions](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages).